# file existing check in xamarin.forms throws error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In xamarin.forms(visual studio) file existing checking time app went to crash like below picture:[image]

In Portable Project :

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad
{
    void SaveData(string fileName, string data);

    string LoadData(string fileName);

    bool FileExists(string fileName);
}
```

In Android Project :

```
  public class FileDiskOperationsAndroid : ISaveAndLoad
{
    public void SaveData(string fileName, string data)
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);
        File.Delete(filePath);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
    }
public bool FileExists(string fileName)
    {
        var documnetsPath = 
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documnetsPath, fileName);
        return File.Exists(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you put dependency for your `FileDiskOperationsAndroid `?

Comment: i am implement ISaveAndLoad interface in android and ios project class like:FileDiskOperationsAndroid , FileDiskOperationsIos

Comment: I know, i think the thing null is probably your `DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad>`. You can split the declaration and the method `fileExist` to check which is the one cause that.

Comment: Thanks  @Lee for your reply

Comment: just to remind you that you need to add dependecy in your `FileDiskOperationsAndroid` before you use `DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad>`